# Classic ASP + TSQL: DateTime Format Issue

Tags: sql-server, datetime, odbc, date-format, datetime-format

I recently transferred a classic ASP website to a new server. The server runs IIS7.5. The site connects to a MS SQL database through ODBC. It's app pool is running under `NETWORK SERVICE`.

Scattered through this enterprise sized website are `datetime` entry fields which have worked fine on the old server, but now they all have the following error:

> *[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

It is expecting the wrong `datetime` format. The format used in the code is consistently `yyyy/MM/dd`. When I swap the month and day positions in the form field, it works. I.e. `yyyy/dd/MM` (which is very weird).

The windows control panel, IIS globalization and `NETWORK SERVICE` user's Registry Keys are all set to en-GB!

I have tested the code all the way to the call to the database and the input looks good. I have then also copied that sql and ran it through SQL Server Management Studio under my own login and that also works fine. ONLY when run through the website (under `NETWORK SERVICE` and through ODBC connection) does it fail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stop passing datetime values across as strings. I'm sure even with ODBC, there's a translation layer that can convert datetime values appropriately. If there *isn't*, then use an unambiguous format. (for dates, it's `YYYYMMDD` with no separators)

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Yes I totally agree. Unfortunately I took over this fully completed project once all the bad habits had already been put in place. And since it worked before, I'd much rather make a configuration change somewhere to better replicate the server than to spend days finding and changing code in multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

You could check and change the default language of your NETWORK SERVICE user's login.

In MS SQL Management Studio search in  the Object Explorer for Security/Login/ and your account name. In the context menu there's Properties entry. Then check for default langauge.

Comment: Thanks, but it's already on British English (which uses the format dd/MM/yyyy). But I pass through yyyy/MM/dd.

Comment: @hofnarwillie - under British English, SQL Server interprets 4/2/2 as `yyyy/dd/MM`, even though no-one in Britain would recognise that format

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ah, ok. Thanks. Still doesn't fix it though. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your ODBC data source on the web server, set the Data Source to "Use Regional settings when outputting currency numbers and dates"...

So,

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Data Sources (ODBC)
Double click your data source
Click Next
Enter a valid db user / password, click next
Select the default DB, then next
Make sure the box as described above is CHECKED, then finish.
```

Answer (score 2):

On IIS, In the application pool for your web application -> advanced settings ->

set the **Load User Profile** option to **TRUE**. This will force the settings to "take" for your pool user.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the [AspLCID metabase property](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b1ffb2a7-3a56-4c98-b65a-77a3f0cccdf7.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS 6, or the LCID property for IIS 7+: [ASP attributes](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp). This is the one used by default.

Comment: What property of the ASP Attributes should be set to solve the problem? I see nothing related to the date format or globalization.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I changed it to 2057 (en-GB) and then to 9 (en), but unfortunately still no results! :(

Comment: Hmm... have you tried the 'Regional' setting for the connection string described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx

Comment: No I haven't, I'll have a go, but I'm not keen on doing that, because the connection string didn't change from the old server.

Comment: I'm not sure from the article how to change the connection string. Sorry, classic asp noob (.net is my game). Currently the connection is created like this:          `SQLConn = "011-002 Sheiiba"`        `Dim conn`
 `SET conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`
 `conn.open SQLConn`

Comment: `"011-002 Sheiiba"` being the odbc source name

Comment: @hofnarwillie - oh, then you need to modify the ODBC DSN using the ODBC Data Source Administrator. There is a dialog page that says 'Use Regional Settings etc...'. While reading it, I'm not sure it's really related, but worth a try.

Comment: Oh right, that was Salvitore's suggestion as well, but didn't work. Thanks anyway